# salesforce functions debugging issue

Tags: salesforce-functions

I am not able to use "Debug Invoke" feature from payload.json -- getting following error:

> Unable to access the function in "/Users/dev/Desktop/dev/FuncitonsDemo3/functions/createfunctions".

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here...any help would be greatly appreciated.